# How to send curl POST variables in POSTMAN

Tags: json, curl, postman

How can I send these details(POST method) in Postman to receive a response as JSON data?

```
curl https://api.mysite.contact/info/regular \
    -d "api_key=xxx" \
    -d "access_token=yyy" \
    -d “name=firstName” \
    -d “address=123” \
    -d “email=test@test.com”
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have tried? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @totoro I think `what have you tried?` should not be threw here. it'll become endless loop if you reply to wrong question with it. especially when the question is quiet useful because the thing you use not well-documented and someone answered your question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you already have a valid `curl` request, you can actually import that and Postman will automatically convert it into a Postman call.

1. From the main menu, click "Import"
2. Click "Paste Raw Text"
3. Paste your curl request and click "Import"

Answer (score 4):

1. Login to Postman
2. Click on plus (+) to add a new tab
3. In the new tab, select POST, and enter the request URL https://api.mysite.contact/info/regular
4. Select Body in the sub-menu, below the URL you entered above
5. Select the form-data radio button
6. Click on Bulk Edit on the left side
7. Paste your parameters in the following format, and press Submit:

> ```
> api_key:xxx
> access_token:yyy
> name:firstName
> address:123
> email:test@test.com
> ```

Then press the Send button

The screen will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks All, i found solution. I used x-www-form-urlencoded to get my desired result.